# Fixed indent for paragraph from left margin regardless of counter's width

Tags: spacing, indentation, titlesec, paragraphs

So what I would like to do is to have a fixed amount between the left margin and where the text starts. I have been able to achieve this for section and subsetion using the following code:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\itshape}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\textup{\thesubsection}}}{0pt}{}
```

I can't make this work for paragraphs, the following

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\theparagraph}}{0pt}{}
```

results in a 0.5 inch space *after* the counter. I am guessing this is because of [runin] but I do not know how to fix this.

EDIT: Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\itshape}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\textup{\thesubsection}}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\theparagraph}}{0pt}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\Alph{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{[\arabic{paragraph}]}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{.5in}{2pt}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{SubSection}
\paragraph{} Text that follows
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:
[image]

What I would like to happen is for T in Text to align with S in Section and Subsection as my paragraphs have no title, they are just numbered (next I would also like to make it so that the paragraph numbering doesn't reset for new subsection but I am assuming I should make that a new post).

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Help us to help you...don't just provide a code snippet, but a small, complete working example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that the OP has provided an MWE, I have revised my answer. Subtract off the width of `\theparagraph` from the size of box one sets for paragraphs, so as to account for `runin`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\itshape}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\textup{\thesubsection}}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{%
  \sbox0{\theparagraph}\makebox[\dimexpr0.5in-\wd0][l]{\theparagraph}}{0pt}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\Alph{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{[\arabic{paragraph}]}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{.5in}{2pt}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{SubSection}
\paragraph{} Text that follows
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

In response to an OP comment/question, can we make the paragraph numbers not reset each section?  Just use a different counter, ref-step it inside of the `\titleformat` and make it part of `\theparagraph`.  I show it working even in the toc, when `tocdepth` is set to 4.

EDIT: I changed, `\sbox0{\theparagraph}` to `\sbox0{[0]}` as it seems that the `runin` is calculated once, based on the initial value of `\theparagraph` and not recalculated as `\theparagraph` grows in width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcounter{globalparagraph}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\itshape}{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\textup{\thesubsection}}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{%
  \refstepcounter{globalparagraph}%
  \sbox0{[0]}\makebox[\dimexpr0.5in-\wd0][l]{\theparagraph}}{0pt}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\Alph{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{[\arabic{globalparagraph}]}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\noindent\rule{.5in}{2pt}

\paragraph{xyz}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{SubSection}
\paragraph{} Text that follows
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{SubSection}
\paragraph{} Text that follows
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and responding, I have edited my question to make my issue more clear.

Comment: @Sam Now you understand the import of a Minimum Working Example, when asking a question.  See my revision.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for. Any chance there is an easy fix for the numbering issue? I want the paragraphs to be numbered consecutively from the start of the document to the end.

Comment: @Sam Please see the supplement to my answer for not resetting paragraph numbers.

Comment: Thank you again! But I just noticed the half inch spacing breaks down once you get to paragraph 10 or higher. It seems it is subtracting more than the width of the counter.

Comment: @Sam Please see my revision

Comment: Thank you so much! You have fixed all the issues I had.

Comment: I found this solution has a minor problem. I made a new post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596859/fixed-indent-for-paragraph-from-left-margin-regardless-of-counters-width-part).