# Fixed indent for paragraph from left margin regardless of counter's width (Part II)

Tags: spacing, indentation, titlesec, paragraphs

Last month I asked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592718/fixed-indent-for-paragraph-from-left-margin-regardless-of-counters-width) question and I got a response that mostly solved the problems I had, however I noticed that the answer has a small problem (a tiny amount of misalignment), here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[letter, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcounter{globalparagraph}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\makebox[0.75in][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\itshape}{\makebox[0.75in][l]{\textup{\thesubsection}}}{0pt}{}
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{%
  \refstepcounter{globalparagraph}%
  \sbox0{[0]}\makebox[\dimexpr0.75in-\wd0][l]{\theparagraph}}{0pt}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{[\arabic{globalparagraph}]}

\begin{document}
\section{ONE}
\subsection{SubSection}
\paragraph{} \textit{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image: Output]

As you can see the start of the paragraph is not fully aligned with the section and subsection titles. I think the dimension of the box needs another tweak but I don't know what that tweak is.

Comment: It seems a "problem" related to the design of the bracket. Try with `\sbox0{[0]}\hskip-.5pt`. I am not completely sure but if you replace `[` with `A` the alignment is as expected.

Comment: The problem went away when I redefined `\theparagraph` to `\Alph{globalparagraph}.` however your proposed solution with `\hskip-.5pt` doesn't work.

Comment: I would argue the issue is with the font, not the method.  If you, not in a sectioning title, but just in successive paragraphs, issue `\par A\par [`, you will see the exact same offset as you show here.  Thus, it has to do with the intrinsic bounding boxes of the `A` and `[`.

Comment: So is there any way of subtracting the width of `[0]` instead of `0`? I don't know the syntax of `\wd`.

Comment: The same issue that you see with Computer Modern happens with Times and Helvetica as well.

Comment: I have a small confusion.   Are you speaking of the alignments of `A` and `[1]` or of `Subsection` and `Subsection`?

Comment: My original question was how to have a fixed indent (0.75in in MWE) for text regardless of the counter. So I want both `A` & `[1]` and `Subsection` & `Subsection` to be aligned.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I subtract the width of `[0]` because `\paragraph` is not set in bold or italic.

Comment: Please see my revision.

Comment: @JohnKormylo An additional reason for subtracting off the width of `[0]` rather than the width of `\theparagraph` is so that, if paragraphs exceed 9 in number, the indent of the paragraph material should not change.

Comment: Titlesec with [runin] adds a gap between the (empty) title and the text.  From the code I have no idea what that gap is, but trial and error shows that it is about 1em.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using italics makes it difficult to judge alignment, so I added `\rule`s.

```
\documentclass[letter, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcounter{globalparagraph}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\makebox[0.75in][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\itshape}{\makebox[0.75in][l]{\textup{\thesubsection}}}{0pt}{}
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{%
  \refstepcounter{globalparagraph}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr 0.75in-1em][l]{\theparagraph}}{0pt}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{[\arabic{globalparagraph}]}

\begin{document}
\section{\rule{0.5pt}{\ht\strutbox}ONE}
\subsection{\rule{0.5pt}{\ht\strutbox}SubSection}
\paragraph{\unskip}\rule{0.5pt}{\ht\strutbox}\textit{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Does the `1em` change depending on what font is used and what size it is?

Comment: It is the gap added by titlesec between the title and the runin text, determined by trial and error.  Titlesecs's source code is largely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues the OP cites:

1. The alignment of the `A` and `[1]`, and
2. The alignment of `SubSection` and `Subsection`.

**ISSUE 1**

The MWE below demonstrates in the code after the sectioning that  issue 1 is not with the method, but with the font.  I won't call it a problem, because the font designer had a reason for setting the bounding boxes thus.  But the reality is that the `A` butts up to the left side of its bounding box, whereas the `[` leaves a small gap.

The typesetting below the sectioning shows the identical horizontal offset of `A` and `[` as the OP has shown in the sectioning.  A possible "fix" for this issue is to kern the bracket leftward when typesetting the `\paragraph`, as follows, by `1pt`:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{%
  \refstepcounter{globalparagraph}%
  \sbox0{[0]}\makebox[\dimexpr0.75in-\wd0][l]{%
  \kern-1pt% <-- THIS CHANGE HERE SHIFTS [ LEFTWARD
  \theparagraph}}{0pt}{}
```

**ISSUE 2**

I do not fully comprehend the reason for issue 2.  However, I am leaning to believe that the 2nd issue is related to a note in the `titlesec` manual that *"The typeset material is in vertical mode with hang, block and display; in horizontal mode with runin*".

I ran some tests with setting `.75in` rules and found that, indeed, the vertical-mode `\section` and `\subsection`, are in fact, tabbed in more that `.75in`, whereas the horizontal mode `\paragraph` is tabbed exactly `.75in`.  So the *ad hoc* "fix" I offer is to shift left the beginning of the `\section` and `\subsection` starting text by `-.6pt`.  I accomplish it as such:

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{%
  \makebox[0.75in][l]{\thesection}}%
  {-.6pt}% <-- SHIFTS SUBSECTION ENTRY LEFT
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\itshape}{\makebox[0.75in][l]%
  {\textup{\thesubsection}}}{-.6pt}% <-- SHIFTS SECTION ENTRY LEFT
  {}
```

Here is the final MWE:

```
\documentclass[letter, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}
\newcounter{globalparagraph}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{%
  \makebox[0.75in][l]{\thesection}}%
  {-.6pt}% <-- SHIFTS SUBSECTION ENTRY LEFT
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\itshape}{\makebox[0.75in][l]%
  {\textup{\thesubsection}}}{-.6pt}% <-- SHIFTS SECTION ENTRY LEFT
  {}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{%
  \refstepcounter{globalparagraph}%
  \sbox0{[0]}\makebox[\dimexpr0.75in-\wd0][l]{%
  \kern-1pt% <-- THIS CHANGE HERE SHIFTS [ LEFTWARD
  \theparagraph}}{0pt}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{[\arabic{globalparagraph}]}
\begin{document}
\section{ONE}
\subsection{SubSection}
\paragraph{}\textit{Subsection}

\noindent\rule{.75in}{3pt}

A

[

\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=.1pt
\fbox{A}

\fbox{[}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Does the `-0.6pt` value change depending on the font, size or both? Also what do you think of Kormylo's solution which looks simpler?

Comment: @Sam Ignore parts of my prior comments.  It seems you did not include paragraph titles in your MWE, to begin with.

Comment: @Sam Yes, font and fontsize can both affect these measurements. As to John's solution, it is, in many ways, more streamlined than mine.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time!